# Login to Firebase using phone number in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to login to firebase by phone number, but when I logged in by phone number, the user have already created. My question is: how can I put some details to the new user like name, email and profile pic who created by  Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)?

```
        Button(action: {
                    let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID")
                    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
                        withVerificationID: verificationID ?? "",
                        verificationCode: confirm)
                     
                        
                        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { success, error in
                            if error == nil {
                               UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
                                Continue = true
                            }
                        
                            else{
                                print(error!)
                                showConfirmError.toggle()
                            }
                        
                       
                        }
                    
                }){
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just link accounts.
Here is official documentation how to do that:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking

Comment: let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
                            withVerificationID: verificationID ?? "",
                            verificationCode: confirm)
                            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { success, error in // code}

Answer (score 1):

for first you must do request like this:

```
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
```

and then change user

```
changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile